# Installing from source could not find devtoolset gcc

Tags: mysql

When I'm trying to install `mysql-8.0.11` from source files on my `Centos-6.8`, `cmake` complains that **GCC 4.8 or newer is required!**

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/mysql \
      -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/mysql/data \
      -DENABLED_LOCAL_INFILE=1 \
      -DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \      
      -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/tmp/mysql.sock \      
      -DSYSCONFDIR=/etc \      
      -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 \      
      -DWITH_SSL=system \      
      -DMYSQL_TCP_PORT=3306 \      
      -DWITH_EXTRA_CHARSETS=all \      
      -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci \      
      -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 \      
      -DWITH_BOOST=/usr/local/include/boost
-- Running cmake version 2.8.12.2
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "1.7.1") 
-- Configuring with MAX_INDEXES = 64U
-- This is Linux version 2.6.32-754.9.1.el6.x86_64
-- gcc is /usr/local/bin/gcc
-- We probably need /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc
-- /usr/local/bin/gcc is version 4.9.1

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:173 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find devtoolset gcc


-- CMAKE_GENERATOR: Unix Makefiles
CMake Error at cmake/os/Linux.cmake:40 (MESSAGE):
  GCC 4.8 or newer is required!
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:239 (INCLUDE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

It seems that cmake asked me to upgrade compilers, so I did it through `yum` command like below.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/scl/slc6-scl.repoyum -y --nogpgcheck 
install devtoolset-3-gcc devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

However, It still doesn't work.

Checking version of gcc and g++ shows me like below.

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-plugin --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --with-mpc=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/mpc-install --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10) (GCC) 

$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-plugin --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --with-mpc=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.1-20140922/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/mpc-install --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10) (GCC)
```

What am I missing?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Append to your cmake line:
`-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++`

Comment: `-DCMAKE_LINKER=.../ld` might be useful too though might work without it.